# I just started to learn Python and I got a little project about Calendar

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar

I need to write a program that will get from the user a date in this format `dd/mm/yyyy` and will print the day of the week of that date. It has to work for past and future dates. What I did so far isn't working and I don't know why.

Here is what I did so far:

```
import calendar
import datetime

date = input("Enter a date:")
dd = int(date[:2])
mm = int(date[3:5])
yyyy = int(date[6:9])

print (calendar.weekday(dd, mm, yyyy))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "What I did so far isn't working and I don't know why." Well, **what happens** when you try it? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? "It isn't working" isn't a description of a problem, and "I don't know why" [isn't a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Comment: You have the arguments to `calendar.weekday()` in the wrong order. It should be `yyyy, mm, dd`

Comment: `date[6:9]` should be `date[6:10]` or simply `date[6:]`. You're missing the last digit of the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to achieve the solution to this problem would be to use datetime's included function `strptime()`. The documentation can be found here: [strptime() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-strptime-function/). This function takes in two arguments:

1. The date string - ex. "12/08/2022"
2. The format string - ex. "%d/%m/%Y"

This will return a datetime object which you can use to pass into the `calendar.weekday()` function. However, it's arguments are in the order: `year, month, day` which you can find here: [weekday() function](https://www.w3resource.com/python/module/calendar/weekday.php).

Then, you can print the output to the terminal by using the `calendar.day_name[]` array and pass it in the result of the `calendar.weekday()` function.

Here is an example code snippet that works regardless of if the user enters leading zeros on single-digit values.

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

date = input("Enter a date:")
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')

print (calendar.day_name[calendar.weekday(date_obj.year, date_obj.month, 
date_obj.day)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the slice wrong for the year, it should be `6:10` to get 4 digits.

But instead of slicing specific digits, you can use `split()` to separate the input string at `/` delimiters.

You have the arguments to `calendar.weekday()` in the wrong order.

```
date = input("Enter a date:")
dd, mm, yyyy = map(int, date.split('/'))

print(calendar.weekday(yyyy, mm, dd))
```

If you want the name of the day instead of a number, use `calendar.day_name` to convert the number to a name.

```
print(calendar.day_name[calendar.weekday(yyyy, mm, dd)])
```